# M2.2 Configurable product with existing simple products - product list empty

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2

I am trying to create a configurable product with existing simple products.

- Catalog -> Product -> New Configurable Product

When I go to the `Configuration` option, I select `Create configurations` since `Add products manually` is not visible.

After I select the configurations and skip the `price`and `quantity` fields now the option `Add products manually` is visible.

When I select that option however, the product list is empty and I get jQuery errors:

[image]

Comment: So, I created a conf. product A by using a specific configuration and the generated simple products. Then I created a conf. product B by using the same configuration. Then after generating the B simple products and selecting `Add products` I could see the A simple products. So I could view only the products created with the same configuration.

Comment: To my knowledge, I couldn't find any post similar to this.